# How to change circle marker attributes (e.g. opacity & fillOpacity) within mapview::addFeatures

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, android-mapview, r-leaflet

I've been able to generate a map in a R-Shiny app that allows multi-selection of markers by combining the mapview, mapedit and leaflet packages.
Functionally everything is fine except I wish to modify the marker attributes, more specifically increase fillOpacity.

The documentation for mapview AddFeatures suggests it should accept the same arguments used by leaflet for addCircleMarkers. I have also tried using the function addCircleMarkers instead of addFeatures without any success.

See [addFeatures doco](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mapview/versions/2.4.0/topics/addFeatures)

> ... Further arguments passed to the respective leaflet::add*
>   functions. See addCircleMarkers, addPolylines and addPolygons.

But it seems to ignore the arguments; weight, opacity and fillOpacity. I have marked in the standalone code below which arguments work or not.

Am I doing something wrong or do you think this is a bug?

```
# devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")
# devtools::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@develop")
# devtools::install_github("bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras")
# devtools::install_github("r-spatial/mapedit")
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)
library(mapedit)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

locnCoord <-
  data.frame(location = c('Sit1','Site2','Site3'),
             lat=c(-18.1, -18.3, -18.4),
             lon=c(145.8, 145.9, 145.9)) %>%
  mutate(depth = runif(3))

locnSF <- st_as_sf(locnCoord, coords = c('lon','lat'), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

#### User input

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.refresh = function() { location.reload(); }"),
  fluidRow(
    # edit module ui
    column(6,
           selectModUI("selectmap"),
           actionButton("refresh", "Refresh Map")
           ),
    column(6,
           h3("Point of Depth"),
           plotOutput("selectstat")
           )
    )
  )

#### Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$refresh, {
    shinyjs::js$refresh()
  })

  g_sel <- callModule(
    selectMod,
    "selectmap",
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addFeatures(
      # addCircleMarkers(
        data = locnSF,
        layerId = ~location,
        stroke = TRUE, # This is effective
        color = 'red', # This is effective
        weight = 150, # This is ignored    ####
        opacity = 0, # This is ignored     ####
        fill = TRUE, # This is effective
        fillColor = 'blue', # This is effective
        fillOpacity=1, # This is ignored   ####
        radius=20) # This is effective
  )

  rv <- reactiveValues(selected=NULL)

  observe({
    gs <- g_sel()

    if(length(gs$id) > 0) {
      rv$selected <- locnSF %>% filter(location %in% gs$id)
    } else {
      rv$selected <- NULL
    }
  })

  output$selectstat <- renderPlot({
    ggplot()
    if(!is.null(rv$selected) && nrow(rv$selected) > 0) {
      ggplot(data=rv$selected, aes(location, depth))+
        geom_point(color='red', size=5)
    } else {
      ggplot()
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not ignored. If you try as a stand-alone mapview call you will see that they work. In your app they are being masked by the mapedit module `selectMod` which allows you set `opacity`, `fillOpacity` and `weight` separately for the case when features are selected and not selected via arguments `styleTrue` and `styleFalse`, respectively. When you set those, you will get the desired behaviour. Thus, change the part where you call the `selectMod` module like below:

```
g_sel <- callModule(
    selectMod,
    "selectmap",
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addFeatures(
        # addCircleMarkers(
        data = locnSF,
        layerId = ~location,
        stroke = TRUE, # This is effective
        color = 'red', # This is effective
        # weight = 150, # This is ignored    ####
        # opacity = 0, # This is ignored     ####
        fill = TRUE, # This is effective
        fillColor = 'blue', # This is effective
        # fillOpacity=1, # This is ignored   ####
        radius=20), # This is effective
    styleFalse = list(fillOpacity = 0.5, weight = 0, opacity = 0), 
    styleTrue = list(fillOpacity = 1, weight = 5, opacity = 1)
  )
```